# Initialize an image from a given path in swift?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, xcode6

I have this code in Objective-C

```
selectedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[_thePath path]];

if (selectedImage.size.width < selectedImage.size.height) {
    imageProportion =selectedImage.size.height /selectedImage.size.width ;
    [selectedImage setSize:NSMakeSize(690.0, 690.0* imageProportion )];
} else{
    imageProportion =selectedImage.size.width /selectedImage.size.height ;
    [selectedImage setSize:NSMakeSize(690.0* imageProportion, 690.0)];
}
[_imageEditorWindow orderFront:nil];
[_imageViewEditor setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(selectedImage.size.width, selectedImage.size.height)];
initialImageSizeH = selectedImage.size.height ;
initialImageSizeW = selectedImage.size.width ;
[_imageViewEditor setImage:selectedImage];
[_imageViewEditor setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(45, 35)];
```

If I write this code in Swift in a Playground I receive an error:

```
var selectedImage = NSImage(byReferencingURL: NSURL (string: "/Users/admin/Desktop/10658771_575156615924178_8253607361793017933_o.jpg")!)
```

> 2014-11-04 15:32:37.582 MyPlayground[2327:701632] CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed this URL which has no scheme: /Users/admin/Desktop/10658771_575156615924178_8253607361793017933_o.jpg
>   Nov  4 15:32:37 imac.inf.ucv.local MyPlayground[2327] : ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination must have at least one image
>   2014-11-04 15:32:37.592 MyPlayground[2327:701632] CGImageDestinationFinalize failed for output type 'public.tiff'

and if i use this code :

```
var selectedImage = NSImage(byReferencingFile: "/Users/admin/Desktop/10658771_575156615924178_8253607361793017933_o.jpg")
```

> ov  4 15:34:56 imac.inf.ucv.local MyPlayground[2331] : ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination must have at least one image
>   2014-11-04 15:34:56.014 MyPlayground[2331:701825] CGImageDestinationFinalize failed for output type 'public.tiff'

So, what is wrong? These errors say that my file is not an image?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for a TIFF representation of the image. Try to add a `NSBitmapImageRep` to the `NSImage`. I have had this issue recently and found that creating an `NSBitmapImageRep` and adding it to the `NSImage` representation cleared.

Assuming that image is an `NSImage` instance

```
let cg = image.CGImageForProposedRect(nil, context: nil, hints: nil)!
let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(CGImage: cg)
image.addRepresentation(self.bitmapRep)
```

Give this a try and see if it works better. Now your methods should be able to get a TIFF representation from the image.

Comment: Can you give an objective-c example of your proposed answer?